# Format Textbox in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that fills textbox with the value in a specific column on the active row.
I have one problem, the column is numeric but has the character"-"
for e.g 0000-00-000-000
I want the textbox to format as 0000000000000 when the form opens.
I use the code below but it doesnt do anything

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim r As Long

    r = ActiveCell.Row

    Me.TextBox1.value = Cells(r, 9).value
    TextBox1.Text = Format(TextBox1.Text, "0000000000000")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` is the function that will manipulate the string as required.

The simplest way would be to simply remove the dashes by replacing them with an empty string

```
TextBox1.Text = replace(TextBox1.Text,"-","")
```